# How to Draw Vertical Line and Horizontal Line in Card Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, draw

How to draw this line in Flutter? Have you any suggestions?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
   Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Your other Widget',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: 1,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Your Widget',
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 50,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Your Widget',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Your Great.

Comment: Most welcome Enjoy your ride with flutter

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, use `Divider` and `VerticalDivider`

```
Column(children: [
  Divider(),
  Row(
      children: [
        Widget()...,
        VerticalDivider(),
        Widget()...
      ]
    )
])
```

Comment: Thanks But Vertical Divider is not showing.

Comment: show code how you tried

Comment: Thanks again, but this is not working i already try it.

Comment: this should work, show the code, maybe you made a mistake, without the code I can't help you

Comment: Create this card